# unix shellscripting connecting to database

Tags: unix

In shell script I am hardcoding username and password  to connect to db.
If the password field has $ followed by numeric value it is considering as the argument or parameter hence not connecting to db.

Please suggest how this can be resolved.

I cannot change the db password

Answer (score 1):

Quote your password with single quotes.

For details, see your friendly manual - open a terminal and type `man sh` or `man bash` (if `bash` is the shell you're using).

The online Bash reference manual also has [pages on quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html).  (I found these with Google, literally within a second.)